# How to ensure local variables are not removed during optimization

Tags: c++, debugging, postmortem-debugging

**Background**

At work I often end up doing postmorten debugging using core dumps of optimized code.

For certain kinds of difficult non-reproducible failures I would like to have extra information available to me. Adding additional traces is not feasible in these cases as the vast majority of calls are successful and would add millions of "unnecessary" traces per minute which will roll the log files quickly. Catching and tracing is not always feasible as well as some errors might corrupt the environment causing traces to fail.

As our core dumps include the callstack memory I thought I could use an area on the callstack memory for "tracing".

**The problem**

Thanks to optimizing compilers code like this don't work

```
void process (int i)
{
   int save_me = i;
   // Do something else
}
```

The idea is to store the input variable on the stack by assigning to a local variable. This often works fine in debug mode but in optimized builds the compiler deems the statement to have no side-effects and removes it.

[`alloca`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) seems like it could work except we target some platforms that don't support `alloca` and I am unsure how well it plays together with C++.

I experimented a bit and the following code seems to be able to make state "stick" on the stack even in optimized builds:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <istream>
#include <sstream>

struct saved_state
{
  saved_state ()
    : head  (0xAABBCCDD)
    , tail  (0xEEFF0000)
  {
    std::fill (state, state + 16, 0);
  }

  void push (std::int32_t input) volatile
  {
    for (auto i = 15U; i > 0U; --i)
    {
      state[i] = state[i - 1];
    }
    state[0] = input;
  }

  volatile std::uint32_t  head      ;
  volatile std::int32_t   state [16];
  volatile std::uint32_t  tail      ;
};

void invoke (std::int32_t i)
{
  if (i > 10)
  {
    throw std::runtime_error ("Busted");
  }
}

void process (std::istream & input)
{
  saved_state volatile ss;

  while (!input.eof ())
  {
    std::int32_t i;
    if (input >> i)
    {
      ss.push (i);
      invoke (i);
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::istringstream input ("1\n2\n30\n");
  process (input);
  return 0;
}
```

**The question**

Can I expect the code to do what I want it to do? It seems to work in for our current set of compilers (clang & gcc) but can I expect it to continue to work?

Is there a better way to achieve what I want to do?

By better I mean simpler, more robust or standard conforming.

Comment: `volatile` means that the loads/stores to the object must not be optimized away, and using it is generally one accepted way of keeping variables alive.

Comment: How are your programs killed?  Would it be feasible to run a handler just before they are killed that could output the wanted information?  Seems both simpler and more robust to me.  For example, if they die due to `std::terminate` being called, you could install a `std::terminate_handler`.

Comment: Often the faults manifests themselves as some kind of low-level exception which trigger a fault hander provide by the platform which collects a lot of information. I am not sure if there's a way for me to hook into that fault-handler and inject information in a reliable way. I will look into it though. Thanks.

Comment: You can possibly instruct the compiler to not optimize the code (at least in Visual Studio). But then you'll not benefit from the optimizations. IMHO you should live with it ans instead learn how to debug optimized code. You don't want to modify the code each time a bug occurs and send a partially `volatile` build to the customer to reproduce the bug and analyze then. Sometimes it will even become irreproducible, not to mention the fact that it is hard to rebuild the exact version a customer uses.

Answer (score 2):

It seems from your question that you have a situation where you know there is a rare / hard-to-debug issue in a particular function / area of the code? I'm assuming this since you are talking about manually instrumenting and I'm guessing you don't plan to do that everywhere speculatively in anticipation of a possible issue.

If this is your situation then I think you might want to consider disabling optimizations for just that function / region of code. In Visual Studio you can do this with a `#pragma` and I imagine something similar exists for clang / gcc. Worst case you can pull the relevant functions out to a separate file and compile just that file without optimizations.

This may not help you for those issues that only show up in optimized builds but when you get to those tricky sort of Heisenbugs, any kind of added tracing can appear to hide the isssue or make it less frequent. In that case your only real recourse is to get really good at deciphering disassembly...

That said, `volatile` does tell the compiler it is not allowed to optimize away reads and writes so your approach should be robust and may be a useful tool for certain kinds of bugs.

Comment: Hi, yes it's true. I am sometimes struggling with difficult errors that needs extra instrumentation. I have been experimenting with disabling optimizations for GCC but I struggled getting it robust (had to force non-inlining and adding empty asm). Apart from feeling rather ugly I don't want to use compiler specifics unless I have to.

Comment: @FuleSnabel If you don't want compiler specific `#pragma`s in your code then putting the relevant functions in a separate object file and compiling just that file without optimizations might be the way to go. That way you mostly contain the ugliness to your build system rather than putting it in your code (although you do end up changing your source file organization).

Answer (score 1):

Optimized compiles can be challenging to debug:

You might try something like:

In your example:

```
void process (int i)
{
   int save_me = i;
   // Do something else
}
```

both the (pre-initialized) formal parameter and the auto variable are on the same stack, just a few bytes apart.  If the crash occurs during "Do something else" the optimizer has already done its thing with the stack items it has no more use for.

What I have some luck with is:

```
void process (int i)
{
   // Do something else

   if (bool_that_compiler_can_not_predetermine_is_always_false)
   {
       std::cerr << "error:  int i is " << i << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Since the compiler can not determine that the cerr line will never be executed, it will generate code, and keep the formal parameter in scope.

Of course there are other actions you might choose beside cerr.  Perhaps a log entry?  Perhaps something smaller.  The point is that the failure in your core dump can not occur after the discard of the value of i (or, if you still need, save_me)  until the end of "process".

Optimzers can also re-order the code, but the location of the if clause at the end of process (I think) forces all parts of do-something-else to be done prior to that clause.

---

I sometimes use time-stamps to create the can-not-be-true-clause.  (because ::time(0) is very efficient).

If you have a main, argc is easy to use, i.e. (0 == argc), or (argc > 100), 
and excess args are easily ignored.